# How does Terraform with a S3 Backend discover all workspaces?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

The S3 terraform stores state files like this.  `${bucket_name}/${workspace_key_prefix}/${workspace_name}/${key}`

Because the state file for a particular Terraform project can contain many workspaces, the state file can exist in many S3 directories.  When doing an init on a new machine, how does Terraform find the state file for all workspaces?  Does it scrape through all locations in S3 to find them all?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is incorrect: "Because the state file for a particular Terraform project can contain many workspaces, the state file can exist in many S3 directories." There will be exactly one state file per workspace. Just look at the S3 prefix, it includes the workspace name. So there can not be a single state file with multiple workspaces in it.

A single project will have multiple state files, one for each workspace. there is no need to scrape the S3 bucket to find state files, because there will only be one state file for the current workspace, and the name of that state file can be calculated exactly from the following pattern: `${bucket_name}/${workspace_key_prefix}/${workspace_name}/${key}`